# No users can log in

Tags: arch-linux, login, password, passwd

Running Arch Linux (KDE). I performed an uneventful update today using `pacman -Syu`. No errors were encountered. Upon rebooting the system no user can log in. In sddm every user is greeted with "Login failed". In a virtual console, every user receives the message "login incorrect".

What could have happened? What would be the steps to fix it?

Initially, I was unable to ssh into the machine either, but after 3 reboots, I got in via ssh (with a key file).

As root, I created a new temp user and set a password. That user was able to ssh into the machine, but is not able to log in at the virtual console.

Here are the additional steps I tried so far (withotu resolution):

- I updated the passwords for all users and tried to login at the virtual console as each user.
- I restored /etc/shadow and /etc/gshadow from the pre-update snapshot and tried again
- checked `pwck` and `grpck` -- each returned no errors
- `systemctl --failed` shows no errors
- UPDATE 1: while logged in via ssh I can `su` to another user, enter that user's password and authentication succeeds. I can do this for all users from the ssh session. However, no users can log in on a virtual console or via sddm still.
- UPDATE 2: I edited /etc/shadow and removed the password hash for the test user account I created (see above), leaving the user with an empty password. Upon logging in on the virtual console, I get an immediate login failure as soon as I enter the username and return key.

For concern that I won't be able to ssh back in, I am not logging out or rebooting the machine until I solve the issue.

**Responses to comments:**

1. Here is the output when running journalctl -f on one terminal or tty and attempting to log in on a virtual console (at the command line).

for testuser1 at virtual console:

```
Jan 03 14:25:44 client1 login[1506]: FAILED LOGIN 1 FROM tty2 FOR testuser1, Authentication failure  
Jan 03 14:25:58 client1 login[1506]: FAILED LOGIN 2 FROM tty2 FOR testuser1, Authentication failure  
Jan 03 14:26:06 client1 login[1506]: FAILED LOGIN 3 FROM tty2 FOR testuser1, Authentication failure  
Jan 03 14:26:13 client1 login[1506]: FAILED LOGIN 4 FROM tty2 FOR testuser1, Authentication failure
```

Here is the log info when attempting to log an actual user in via sddm:

```
Jan 03 14:36:01 client1 sddm-helper[1594]: [PAM] authenticate: Authentication failure
Jan 03 14:36:01 client1 sddm-helper[1594]: [PAM] returning.
Jan 03 14:36:01 client1 sddm[622]: Authentication error: "Authentication failure"
Jan 03 14:36:01 client1 sddm-greeter[687]: Message received from daemon: LoginFailed
Jan 03 14:36:01 client1 sddm-helper[1594]: [PAM] Ended.
Jan 03 14:36:01 client1 sddm[622]: Auth: sddm-helper exited with 1
```

2. the disk is only 15% full
3. regarding "are the users on the X group? Who has the ownership of the desktop configurations?", I do not understand this question. File ownerships were not changed by running `pacman -Syu`. And X would not affect logging in at the virtual console, so I don't believe this is relevant to the issue.
4. a diff on the prior snapshot and /etc/pam.d shows no differences. In particular, /etc/pam.d/system-auth and /etc/pam.d/su are unchanged from before the update.

Comment: are the users on the X group? Who has the ownership of the desktop configurations?

Comment: What log output do you get when running `journalctl -f` on one terminal or tty and attempting to log in on another one?

Comment: How full is the disk? If it is try clearing out some space as a full disk can prevent logins. Otherwise you should check the logs/dmesg and could try reinstalling some packages, in particular from the base group. Note that if you lose ssh access you can still get a live usb and chroot into the system.

Comment: The fact that you can su to another user but you're getting PAM failures in journalctl output suggests that your PAM configuration got screwed up.  What does your PAM stack look like? Probably `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` and `/etc/pam.d/su` would be useful places to start.

Comment: Both the [`sddm`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/sddm/) and [`kwallet-pam`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/kwallet-pam/) packages have been recently updated.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. Would sddm or kwallet-pam affect ability to login at a virtual console?

Comment: @jayhendren - see update in my question. I do not see any differences in /etc/pam.d/system-auth and /etc/pam.d/su compared to the prior snapshot.

Comment: What about any other files in /etc/pam.d?

Comment: question updated again with all answers to comment questions. Thanks